# Equivalent definition of abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, semigroups

Assuming that given operation is commutative and associative, are following definitions equivalent?

1) A zero element $e_0$ exists such that $e_i+e_0=e_i$ and inverse $e_{i'}$ exists for every $e_i$ such that $e_i+e_{i'}=e_0$

and

2) For every pair of elements $e_i$ and $e_j$ there exists an element $e_k$ such that $e_i+e_k=e_j$

Comment: A difference is that the former is false for the empty set while the latter is true for the emptyset. This might not be what you are looking for though.

Comment: Have you tried proving the equivalence yourself? For instance, given (2), can you prove that $e_0$ exists?

Comment: @Curious I changed the title and tags to be about [abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group), since as written, the question has nothing to do with fields or vector spaces. I hope that's ok with you.

Comment: Thanks for giving an appropriate title

Comment: I've asked a [follow-up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454503/is-every-semigroup-with-possibly-non-unique-division-a-group).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not equivalent. For example, let $S$ be any set, and let $+$ be the operation on $S$ given by $a + b = b$ for all $a,b\in S$. This satisfies (2) but not (1).

The issue here that you might be overlooking is that (1) says that there exists a single element $0$ which satisfies $a+0 = a$ for *all* $a$, while (2) only guarantees that for each $a$ there is *some* element $b$ such that $a + b = a$. It might be different for every $a$.

Now, you might complain that the $+$ operation in my example isn't commutative. If you mean to ask whether (1) and (2) are equivalent relative to some other axioms about $+$, you should specify exactly what axioms you have in mind.

---

**Edit:** Now that you've edited the question to add associative and commutativity of $+$, I can give a better answer. By the way, if $(S,+)$ is a set with an associative commutative operation, we call $S$ a commutative semigroup. Adding (1) makes $S$ an abelian group.

First, it's clear that (1) $\implies$ (2): Given $a$ and $c$ in an abelian group, and letting $b = (-a) + c$, we have $a + b = c$. In fact, we get something stronger, let's call it

(2'): For all $a$ and $c$ there exists a *unique* $b$ such that $a + b = c$.

Indeed, if we have $a + b = c$, then adding $(-a)$ to both sides, we must have $b = (-a) + c$.

Wikipedia calls (2') the [Latin square property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square_property).

Now it turns out that also (2')$\implies$ (1). A binary operation satisfying (2') (for addition on the right and the left), but not necessarily associativity or commutativity, is called a "quasigroup", and [every associative quasigroup is a group](http://www.planetmath.org/anassociativequasigroupisagroup). The argument is simpler than the one in the link if we assume commutativity, so I'll give it here.

Identity: Let $x$ be any element of $S$, and let $e$ be the unique element such that $x + e = x$. Now let $y$ be any other element. We have $x + (y+e) = (x + e) + y = x + y$, so both $b = y+e$ and $b = y$ satisfy the equation $x + b = x + y$. Again by uniqueness, $y + e = y$. So $e$ is an identity element for $(S,+)$.

Inverses: Now that we have $e$, (2') gives inverses easily. For any $x$, let $(-x)$ be the unique element of $S$ such that $x + (-x) = e$.

So we've established that (1) is equivalent to (2'). Is it equivalent to (2)? I don't actually know... But here's an observation: Given $(S,+)$ for all $a$, there is a function $f_a\colon S\to S$ given by $f_a(x) = a+x$, and if $S$ satisfies (2), then $f_a$ is surjective for all $a$. Since any surjective function from a finite set to itself is also injective, any *finite* commutative semigroup satisfying (2) must also satisfy (2'). So any counterexample to the equivalence of (1) and (2) must be infinite. Maybe someone else can provide one or a proof that (2) $\implies$ (2') for commutative semigroups.

---

**Edit 2:** A proof that (2) $\implies$ (2') has been given in an answer to my [follow-up question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454503/is-every-semigroup-with-possibly-non-unique-division-a-group)

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question

Answer (score -1):

I'll make an attempt to answer although algebra is not my strongest area..

First of all. A *field* has two operations. What you seem to be talking about are a requirements on one of these operations which obey the axioms of a *group*.

1. Existance of zero or neutral element means there is one element
   which if operated together with any other element yields that other element. This is a requirement for a group. However you clump it together with the inverse, which is a separate requirement. It is possible to have neutral elements without any inverse coupling between group elements.
2. This is the *closure* requirement of a group. That the "result" of the operation between any two elements must stay in the group.

Comment: I think you read (2) wrong - it doesn't say that for all $a$ and $b$ there exists $c$ such that $a+b = c$ (this is closure), but rather that for all $a$ and $c$ there exists $b$ such that $a+b = c$.

Comment: Oh, right. That is why you should not answer right before going to bed. Must've been tired. Will read again.