# An AE axiomatization of groups

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $L=\{*\}$. The usual axiomatization of groups in this language has the EA axiom $\exists{e}\forall{x}$ $ e*x = x$. But the union of a chain of groups is also a group. This means that the theory of groups has an AE axiomatization. My question is, what is a system of AE axioms for groups.

I want to replace the above axiom with $\exists{y}$ ${y^2=y}$. But I have had trouble showing that the axiom system leads to the theory of groups.

Comment: Why not just add the constant symbol $1$ to the language? If you also add $-^{-1}$, you get a completely universal axiomatization of groups.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: That is true. But I'm interested in seeing and axiomatization in this language. The theorems tell us that one exists, so.....

Comment: Hint: There's one visible just a little below this comment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you add the axiom $\exists e\,\, e^2=e$ and also cancellation laws $ab=ac\implies b=c$ and $ba=ca\implies b=c$. Then $xe^2=xe$, which implies $xe=x$ by cancellation.

Comment: +1. Just to be perfectly explicit: note that the cancellation laws are of the form "$\forall \overline{x}[$quantifier-free stuff$]$."

Answer (score 1):

Another cute axiomatization is

- $\exists x\, x = x$ (just to rule out the empty structure, if you allow it)
- $\forall x\,\forall y\,\forall z\,(xy)z = x(yz)$
- $\forall x\,\forall y\,\exists z\, xz = y$
- $\forall x\,\forall y\,\exists z\, zx = y$

It's a bit more complicated to show that every model of these axioms is a group, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454503/is-every-semigroup-with-possibly-non-unique-division-a-group).

Comment: Thanks Alex. Out of curiosity, did you have an answer to my question about dividing?